# logstash text file output configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder

Hey i have a text file containing many lines each line contain 3 values separated by space:

```
username email hash
username email hash
username email hash
username email hash
username email hash
```

i tried indexing the list with logstash using this config:

```
    input {
        file {
                path => "/path/to/your/file.log"
                start_position => beginning
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}
filter {
        grok {
                match => {"message" => "%{WORD:username} %{WORD:email} %{WORD:hash}" }
        }
}
output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        }
}
```

my problem is that logstash index it like that:

```
        {
  "_index": "logstash-2017.06.01",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "AVxinqK5XRvft8kN7Q6M",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "path": "C:/Users/user/Desktop/user/log.txt",
    "@timestamp": "2017-06-01T07:46:22.488Z",
    "@version": "1",
    "host": "DESKTOP-FNGSJ6C",
    "message": "username email password",
    "tags": [
      "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1496303182488
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1496303182488
  ]
}
```

and i want it to be like that:

```
        {
  "_index": "logstash-2017.06.01",
  "_type": "db",
  "_id": "AVxinqK5XRvft8kN7Q6M",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "username": "Marlb0ro",
    "email": "Marlb0ro@site.com",
    "hash": "123456",
}
```

what can i do to change it? any help will be apricated

Answer (score 1):

There is a parsing error when I try test your grok in http://grokconstructor.appspot.com. Since space is the delimiter, I tried using NOTSPACE for the username and email:

```
%{NOTSPACE:username} %{NOTSPACE:email} %{WORD:hash}
```

Comment: Sorry, GhostCat, it was an honest mistake. I was supposed give an answer but I clicked comment. I edited it tho. :)

Comment: Yes, looks much better now.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that your grok parser won't work. Because the pattern "Word" won't match for a Hash or EMail Adress.

You can check their pre defined patterns on their github page ([here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns))

There is an "EMAILADDRESS" pattern and for the hash I would use "Username".